# How to connect rally with Object Id of project

Tags: python-3.x, rally, pyral

I am trying to connect rally workspace and project with pyral by project name but I need to connect rally with project object id.
 Could any one help me. I couldn’t find any option to connect rally with object Id through pyral.

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal of such an approach?

Comment: In case of team changes the project name of rally no need for another configuration if we go with Object Id.

Comment: Any suggestions or comments.

Answer (score 0):

This code will connect to Rally using your default Workspace and Project, then displays all Workspaces and Projects that your UserID has access to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from pyral import Rally, rallySettings, RallyRESTAPIError

my_server      = "rally1.rallydev.com"
my_username    = "user@company.com"
my_password    = ".............."
rally = Rally(my_server, my_username, my_password)

workspaces = rally.getWorkspaces()
for wksp in workspaces:
    print("    Worspace: ObjectID=%12s  Name='%s'" % (wksp.oid, wksp.Name))
    projects = rally.getProjects(workspace=wksp.Name)
    for proj in projects:
        print("            Project: ObjectID=%12.12s  Name='%s'" % (proj.oid, proj.Name))

sys.exit()
```